# How HTML to PDF works (specially abcPDF)

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

My new project is converting the HTML into PDF on the fly using the URL.
I have searched a lot in my initial period and come up with the solution so that HTML convert to IMAGE and IMAGE goes to PDF.
But its not ideal solution as user can not copy paste from the PDF file.

Recently i came across abcPDF component, you can check their demo here http://www.abcpdfeditor.com/

Now i am wondering how they are able to produce such a nice PDF with all such feature. What will be their logic? I dont think they are going to parse each and every HTML tag to create document. Do you guys have any idea?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: they must use some kind of HTML parser/render engine - like WebKit or similar... but I think this question is far too general for SO !

Comment: @Yahia Ok i got that, but how they get the web kit output to PDF? Its not an image. How can one build a PDF from the given HTML? I dont have any idea here

Comment: I don't think that you understand what SO is about... SO is for specific programming questions... your question is far too general, one could write a whole book as answer...

Comment: @Yahia I thought SO = Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2):

In short, this is how most HTML to PDF conversion works.

HTML  ----Converted To ---->  EMF (Metafile/Vector Image) ----> PDF

1. Basically,  IE's rendering engine (i.e, MSHTML) has some APIs through which you can export loaded HTML page as Emf (Enhanced metafile format) which is nothing but a vector image.

You can make use of this open-source web browser control for this purpose.
http://groups.google.com/group/csexwb

1. Then you have to render the generated EMF file on to PDF page.  This is typically called as,  EMF to PDF conversion.  Based on my understanding there is no free Emf to PDF conversion software available.  But ITextsharp provides minimal support for WMF format.